# Capture all key strokes from JFrame

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

So I am having problem with InputMap and Keystrokes as they are not working. So I want to capture all keyevent pressed inside frame doesn't matter on which component they are generated.

Please don't give suggestions about key binding as I had already used and found it useless :(

Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: I suggest that you post your code and also post what you want your code to do and what it is actually doing. I assume that what your code is actually doing is not what you want it to do.

Comment: Using the inputmap and keystrokes is using key bindings. Some components will handle the events by default when they have focus. You can make them non-focusable or set their inputmap to handle the events. What components are you using.